# Как в ad-gallery дописать lightbox?

Tags: javascript, jquery, lightbox

Всем привет! Вот с чем столкнулся. Нужно в ad-gallery засунуть lightbox. Дело в том, что jquery я очень плохо знаю (только могу скрипт на сайт поставить и настроить). Галерея выводится через jquery, ссылку я дописал, но такое ощущение что конфликтует ad-gallery и lightbox, т.к. когда открываешь галерею и пытаешься открыть картинку открывается как просто картинка без js.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте, когда загружается страничка, запустить "Консоль ошибок" (<kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>J</kbd>) в FireFox или посмотрите Resources (правая кнопка мыши -> "Просмотр кода элемента" -> Кнопка "Resources") в Chrome - они достаточно ясно показывают эти самые конфликты.

Когда найдете проблемную переменную, попробуйте изменить ее имя во всем исходнике скрипта ad-gallery, если lightbox написан на jquery (phantom, prototype или любой другой фреймворк), или в lightbox'е, если он на чистом js.